# Ubuntu OS installation on Baremetal Server

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

We are in verge of creating an automated script for OS installation on Bare metal server.

We tried using Cobbler , however the DRAC version was getting supported only till 6. However, we have only DRAC 7 with us.

Moreover, the installation of Razor + Puppet went unsuccessful since it was more tedious.

Is there any other tool available for Deploying Ubuntu OS on Bare metal server ?

```
If we use drac5 as power type
The output of “cobbler system reboot --name=ubuntu-server-system_dell”
            running: /usr/sbin/fence_drac5
            received on stdout:
            received on stderr: Unable to connect/login to fencing device

If we use drac as power type
The output of “cobbler system reboot --name=ubuntu-server-system_dell”
            running: /usr/sbin/fence_drac
            Regex match timed out.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Landscape** (not free): https://landscape.canonical.com

**Foreman**: http://theforeman.org